# How can object properties 'talk' to each other without a method?

Tags: javascript, html, oop

i know that once a function is called, the context of `this` changes to the object, but how can i simulate that context without having to create a method?

```
var object = {
    x: 1,
    y: object.x,       // will NOT work
    z: function () {
        return this.x  // works fine
    }
}
console.log(object.z())
```

Comment: Are you asking how to refer to an object during its creation? If so, you can do it by using an anonymous constructor instead of object literal syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but let me introduce *getter* functions. Like

```
var object = {
    x: 1,
    get y() {
        return this.x;
    },
    z: function () {
        return this.x  // works fine
    }
}
console.log(object.y); // 1
```

Such a method is still a function, but it behaves like a property.
Maybe this will help you in any way. Having that said, there is no way or more precisely, no syntax in Javascript where you can access object properties the way you propose.

Comment: Be careful!  This is part of the ES6 spec, and is not widely implemented in browsers yet.  Best to make sure this works in your target environment, and use an `Object.defineProperty` fallback if it isn't supported.

Comment: @EthanBrown Actually, the `get` and `set` keywords were also part of ES5 (maybe even ES3 I'm not sure) and it should be absolute of no concern.

Comment: Oh, right you are...I was thinking of computed name property accessors.  You are correct.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered. This was mostly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when `y` is created, `object` doesn't exist yet. It is still being created. When you actually call `object.z()`, the object has already been created and it works.

**EDIT:**
You could do something like this, creating a constructor for the object:

```js
function getObject(){
    this.x=1;
    this.y=this.x;
    return this;
}

var object = getObject();
alert(object.y)
```

Or this, if you know what the value should be when you write the code:

```js
var object = {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
}
alert(object.y)
```

Creating the variable first. This may be what you want if you will know what x should be by the time the object is created, but not as you are writing the code.

```js
var one=1;

var object = {
    x: one,
    y: one,
}
alert(object.y);
```

All these will put 1 into y.

You could also try this. If both values are the same, why do you need both? (Maybe if they will be changing independently? I don't know where this would happen, but it's possible)

```js
var object={
  x: 1
}
alert(object.x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you can't."  You have a few options.  The first is to store any values you wish to use in advance (I've left off `z` in these examples for brevity):

```
var x = 1;
var object = {
    x: x,
    y: x,
};
```

The second is to wait until after object construction (this is what I usually do) and then assign the property, since objects are mutable:

```
var object = {
    x: 1
};
object.y = object.x;
```

The third is to create an object constructor and do the assignment there:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = this.x;
}
var object = new MyObject();
```